# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, microsoft-edge

I am running selenium test cases in the azure devops pipeline for Microsoft edge browser. One strange issue is happening i.e. intermittently I am getting the issue Session Not Created Exception for msedge browser and it is showing message as Message: unknown error: cannot find msedge binary. I am not changing any version or any binaries inside the vm. Below are the details of my VM - `os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'

Webdriver Manager - 5.3.2

testNG - 6.14.3

org.seleniumhq.selenium - 4.5.0

msedge browser version - 112.0.1722.58

System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2016',

os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',

java.version: '17.0.6'

```
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
if(incognito.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
   edgeOptions.addArguments("inprivate");
   }
edgeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs",p);
WebDriverManager webDriverManager = WebDriverManager.edgedriver();
webDriverManager.config().setEdgeDriverVersion("112.0.1722.58");
webDriverManager.setup();
this.driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
```

this above code I am writing to to initialize Edge browser inside Azure VM. 2 out of 5 times this is working and all the tests are executing successfully but rest of the time it is getting failed with the exception -

org  .openqa. selenium. SessionNotCreatedException : Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find msedge binary

System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver

Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, inprivate], extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: D:\VSTSAgentsWork\01\292\s\...}}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, inprivate], extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: D:\VSTSAgentsWork\01\292\s\...}}}}]

Starting Microsoft Edge WebDriver 112.0.1722.58 (4dc3f55bfaec25ee4e6acc8bd6b20d64b3b0b7bb) on port 31244

To submit feedback, report a bug, or suggest new features, please visit https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver

Only local connections are allowed.

Please see https://aka.ms/WebDriverSecurity for suggestions on keeping Microsoft Edge WebDriver safe.

Microsoft Edge WebDriver was started successfully.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find msedge binary

Only local connections are allowed. Please see https://aka.ms/WebDriverSecurity for suggestions on keeping Microsoft Edge WebDriver safe.

Microsoft Edge WebDriver was started successfully. org. openqa. selenium. SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find msedge binary

Comment: Will the error show if you run the code locally instead of with Azure Devops? I have no idea how to work with Azure Devops, but usually we need to put webdriver in PATH when we run Selenium automation locally. Besides, can you assign the binary path of `msedge.exe` in your code and test again?

Comment: Yes I have provided the path and I am not running it through webdriver manger , msedgedriver.exe is present under my project folder, still the issue is coming.

Comment: Does the webdriver version match the Edge version? From your code, it looks like you're using WebDriver Manager, could you please provide the code snippet you use without WebDriver Manager? Besides, do you have a local environment to test as I think that might be an issue with Azure Pipeline?

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, it is resolved now. Microsoft edge browser was not installed in the VM. installing MS Edge fixed the issue.